# How to insert tikzpicture in thmtools environment?

Tags: tikz-pgf, minipage, thmtools

```
\documentclass[12pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{amsthm, thmtools}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{blindtext}


\declaretheoremstyle[
  headfont={\normalsize\bfseries},
  bodyfont=\footnotesize,
  spaceabove=10pt,
  spacebelow=10pt
]{comm}
\declaretheorem[title={Example}, numberlike=section, style=comm]{myexample}

\begin{document}

\blindtext[1]

\begin{myexample}
  Good example. Blablabla blabla blablablablablabla blabla blablablablablabla blabla
  Blablabla blabla blablablablablabla blabla blablablablablabla blabla
\end{myexample}

\blindtext[1]

\begin{myexample}
  \begin{minipage}{0.7\linewidth}
      Bad example. Blablabla blabla blablablablablabla blabla blablablablablabla blabla
      Blablabla blabla blablablablablabla blabla blablablablablabla blabla
  \end{minipage}
  \begin{minipage}{0.3\linewidth}
      \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]
          \coordinate (A) at (0, 0);
          \coordinate (B) at (2, 0);
          \coordinate (C) at (1, 1);
          \coordinate (D) at (2, 2);
          \path [draw=black, fill=black] (A) circle (2pt);
          \path [draw=black, fill=black] (B) circle (2pt);
          \path [draw=black, fill=black] (C) circle (2pt);
          \path [draw=black, fill=black] (D) circle (2pt);
      \end{tikzpicture}
  \end{minipage}
\end{myexample}

\blindtext[1]

\end{document}
```

I want to give an example inside my pdf and accompany the example with a tikzpicture. I know, how to use minipage environment in such cases, but my code produces the following result:

[image]

As you can see I have troubles with vertical alignment. I want "Example 2" to be in the same line as "Bad example". Also the tikzpicture must be not higher than the first line of "Example 2".

How can I do that? Would you suggest to use different tools instead of minipage?

Comment: add option `[t]` to the `minipage` environ as in the answer below

Comment: please see if the answer below suits the requirement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- as already  mentioned @jsbibra, to `minipage` you need to add option `[t]`
- for `tikzpicture` you not need `minipage`, but you need to set its baseline to highest circle in the image:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}
\usepackage{amsthm, thmtools}
\declaretheoremstyle[
  headfont={\normalsize\bfseries},
  bodyfont=\footnotesize,
  spaceabove=10pt,
  spacebelow=10pt
]{comm}
\declaretheorem[title={Example}, numberlike=section, style=comm]{myexample}
%---------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

\blindtext[1]

\begin{myexample}
  Good example. Blablabla blabla blablablablablabla blabla blablablablablabla blabla
  Blablabla blabla blablablablablabla blabla blablablablablabla blabla
\end{myexample}

\blindtext[1]

\begin{myexample}
  \begin{minipage}[t]{0.7\linewidth}
      Bad example. Blablabla blabla bla blabla blablabla blabla bla blablabla blabla blabla
      Blablabla blabla blablablablablabla blabla blablablabla blabla blabla
  \end{minipage}\hfil % or \hfill
    \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(D.south), scale=0.5,
  dot/.style = {circle, fill, minimum size=4pt, inner sep=0pt}
                        ]
  \node (A) [dot] {};
  \node (B) [dot] at (2, 0) {};
  \node (C) [dot] at (1, 1) {};
  \node (D) [dot] at (2, 2) {};
      \end{tikzpicture}
\end{myexample}

\blindtext[1]

\end{document}
```

[image]
(red lines shows text borders)

Answer (score 1):

```
  \begin{minipage}[t]{0.7\linewidth}
      Bad example. Blablabla blabla blablablablablabla blabla blablablablablabla blabla
      Blablabla blabla blablablablablabla blabla blablablablablabla blabla
  \end{minipage}
```

[image]

**EDIT**

```
\begin{myexample}
  \begin{minipage}[t]{0.7\linewidth}
      Bad example. Blablabla blabla blablablablablabla blabla blablablablablabla blabla
      Blablabla blabla blablablablablabla blabla blablablablablabla blabla
  \end{minipage}
  \begin{minipage}[t]{0.3\linewidth}
      \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=1.9cm][scale=1]
          \coordinate (A) at (0, 0);
          \coordinate (B) at (2, 0);
          \coordinate (C) at (1, 1);
          \coordinate (D) at (2, 2);
          \path [draw=black, fill=black] (A) circle (2pt);
          \path [draw=black, fill=black] (B) circle (2pt);
          \path [draw=black, fill=black] (C) circle (2pt);
          \path [draw=black, fill=black] (D) circle (2pt);
      \end{tikzpicture}
  \end{minipage}
\end{myexample}
```

[image]

Comment: I've tried that, but the tikzpicture in that case is over the first line. Is there a way to put it lower?

Comment: have look now with baseline option to `tikz` environ